# bash concatenate string variables while preserving the line feeds inside the strings

Tags: bash

I have a variable A containing two lines, 33, and 44 as below

```
A="$(echo 33; echo 44)"
```

And I know I need to use double quote to show it, and it looks fine (with 2 line feeds)

```
$ echo "$A" | hexdump -C
00000000  33 33 0a 34 34 0a                                 |33.44.|
00000006
```

Now, when I concatenate with the last "55", the line feed after "44" is gone as shown below:

```
$ A="$A""55"

$ echo "$A" | hexdump -C
00000000  33 33 0a 34 34 35 35 0a                           |33.4455.|
00000008
```

I expected the mentioned problem to output 3 lines, but instead it shows two lines only.

Comment: Hi. In the spirit of this forum, what is your question? Yes, this is what happens. You are preserving the line feeds in your variable. The variable does not store the trailing line feed in the first place.

Comment: 1. Avoid UPPER case in variable names, 2. Try: `echo ${a}$'\n'55`

Comment: KamilCuk is right.  However, if I have known that a variable cannot store the trailing line feed at the first place, I won't be asking this question, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(...)` command substitution **removes** all trailing newlines. The second newline comes from `echo`, `echo` outputs a newline. The variable itself does *not* store trailing newline. The variable stores *one* newline.

Use `declare -p` to debug variables. Your variable stores `33\n44`:

```
$ declare -p A
declare -- A="33
44"
```

If you want to add a newline followed by `55`, do that:

```
A+=$'\n'55
```

If you want your variable to store a trailing newline, add a newline:

```
A=$(...)$'\n'
```

Fun fact, these two lines are equivalent:

```
A=$(echo 33; echo 44)
A=$(echo 33; echo 44; echo; echo; echo; echo; echo; printf "\n\n\n\n\n")
```